# How to delete custom object

Tags: custom-object

I created a couple of custom objects as I was testing something and I would like to remove them.

My Salesforce layout/theme is Lightning and when I login I go to Setup > Objects and Fields > Object Manager.

I can see the 2 custom objects I created but in the drop down there is no Delete option.

The profile type of the logged in account is System Admin and it has the Customize Application permission.

How can I delete these custom objects?

Comment: This might be an omission in the UI, but I'm pretty sure it used to be there at late as Winter '17. I'll ask someone about it. However, if you'd rather not switch to Classic, you can click on the Schema Builder, add the custom object to the layout, and use the gear icon to delete the custom object.

Comment: Schema builder saved the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Help Doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_deleting_custom_objects.htm&type=0):

> "Delete Custom Objects" is only **Available in Salesforce Classic** as
>   of now.

Anyway, based on my personal experience so far, don't use Lightning UI to do administration work now... It is not user-friendly and some features not works...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug - In classic, delete is clearly there, however, not in lightning as the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_deleting_custom_objects.htm&type=0) states.

Classic:

[image]

Lightning:

[image]

I tested using a Dev org in Spring '17.